# Как написать скрипт на Lua для вывода клиентского баланса в терминале Quick

Tags: lua

Ситуация странная. Есть рабочий код, который работал буквально до сегодняшнего дня. На данный момент не выводит баланс по какой-то причине. Выдает ошибку: "attempt to index a nil value (global 'moneyRu')". Уже пробовал и менять различные параметры таблицы - бесполезно. Кто знает в чем может быть проблема.

```
function main()
Firm_ID = "MC0139600000"
client_code = "4105TE1"
moneyRu = getMoneyEx(Firm_ID, client_code, "EQTV", 'SUR',0)
message('Баланс RUB = '..moneyRu.currentbal)
end
```

Comment: moneyRu у вас nil. А почему у вас nil, наверное в getMoneyEx можно понять.